# Couldn't find the header height. Are you inside a screen in Stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I am nesting stack navigators inside Drawer like this?

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const renderDrawerItem = (props: DrawerContentComponentProps) => {
  const langCode = translations.getLanguage();
  const DRAWER_LIST = [
    {
      name: RouteNames.Dashboard,
      title: getTranslatedPageTitle(RouteNames.Dashboard, langCode),
      img: HomeIcon,
    },
    {
      name: RouteNames.QueueHistoryStack,
      title: getTranslatedPageTitle(RouteNames.QueueHistory, langCode),
      img: QueueIcon,
    },
    {
      name: RouteNames.InviteFriendsStack,
      title: getTranslatedPageTitle(RouteNames.InviteFriends, langCode),
      img: InviteIcon,
    },
    {
      name: RouteNames.FAQStack,
      title: getTranslatedPageTitle(RouteNames.FAQ, langCode),
      img: FAQIcon,
    },
    {
      name: RouteNames.SettingsStack,
      title: getTranslatedPageTitle(RouteNames.Settings, langCode),
      img: SettingsIcon,
    },
    {
      name: RouteNames.SelectLanguageStack,
      title: getTranslatedPageTitle(RouteNames.SelectLanguage, langCode),
      img: TranslateIcon,
    },
  ];

  return DRAWER_LIST.map((item) => (
    <DrawerItem
      label={item.title}
      icon={({ size }) => (
        <FastImage source={item.img} style={{ width: size, height: size }} />
      )}
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(item.name)}
      key={item.name}
      labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
    />
  ));
};

const DrawerContent = (props: DrawerContentComponentProps) => {
  const langCode = translations.getLanguage();

  return (
    <View style={styles.maxFlex}>
      <DrawerContentScrollView>
        <View style={styles.greetings}>
          <UserGreeting />
        </View>

        <View>
          {renderDrawerItem(props)}

          <DrawerItem
            label={getTranslatedPageTitle(RouteNames.LogOut, langCode)}
            icon={({ size }) => (
              <FastImage
                source={LogoutIcon}
                style={{ width: size, height: size }}
              />
            )}
            onPress={() => {}}
            labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
          />
        </View>
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
const DrawerRoutes = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator
    initialRouteName={RouteNames.Dashboard}
    drawerContent={(props: DrawerContentComponentProps) => (
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
      <DrawerContent {...props} />
    )}
    hideStatusBar
    statusBarAnimation="fade"
  >
    <Drawer.Screen name={RouteNames.SettingsStack} component={SettingsRoutes} />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name={RouteNames.SelectLanguageStack}
      component={SelectLanguageRoutes}
    />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
);
```

Below, I am adding the stack navigators:

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();
const SettingsRoutes = () => (
  <SettingsStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: headerStyle(useHeaderHeight()),
    }}
  >
    <SettingsStack.Screen name={RouteNames.Settings} component={Settings} />
  </SettingsStack.Navigator>
);

const SelectLanguageStack = createStackNavigator();
const SelectLanguageRoutes = () => (
  <SelectLanguageStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: headerStyle(useHeaderHeight()),
    }}
  >
    <SelectLanguageStack.Screen
      name={RouteNames.SelectLanguage}
      component={SelectLanguage}
    />
  </SelectLanguageStack.Navigator>
);
```

`headerStyle` accepts the height and applies some common styling:

```
export const headerStyle = (headerHeight: number) => ({
  height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? headerHeight + 20 : headerHeight - 10,
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderBottomColor: DEFAULT_STYLE.$accent1,
});
```

I am getting the error mentioned in the title. Not sure why `useHeaderHeight()` can't calculate the height. It breaks the code. I'm assuming the. the function is trying to calculate the height before the screen gets loaded. Thanks, I anticipation.

Comment: Have you declare `useHeaderHeight()` ? something like `const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that too inside the component. It throws the same error

Comment: Same thing happens to me when I try to pass `useHeaderHeight()` as `route.params`. And if I decalare it as `const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();` and try to use it, I get `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` error.

Comment: @RobiZzT So, I went with a workaround which suits my case. I pass a custom header to `header` props in options. e.g

`<HomeStack.Screen options={{ header: () => <MyHeaderComponent />  }}`

Not sure, if this solution suits your case.